# How do you test code inside the main function

Tags: go

Consider the following trivial `main.go` file:

```
package main

type myStruct struct {
   songs []string
}

func main() {
  s1 := myStruct{
    songs:[]string{"Master of Puppets", "Battery"}
  }
  foo(s1)
}

func foo(s myStruct) {
  // Does something with s
}
```

I get how I could test the `foo` function. But how could I test that the main function properly intializes the `s1` struct and assert that the `foo` function get's called with `s1` as an argument?

Comment: It is going to be hard to test something that has no observable behaviour.

Comment: Move whatever you want to unit test outside main.

Comment: Test an initialization? Why would you do that?

Answer (score -1):

Why not try our most basic debug tool: printf.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myStruct struct {
   songs []string
}

func main() {
  s1 := myStruct{songs:[]string{"Master of Puppets", "Battery"}}
  foo(s1)
}

func foo(s myStruct) {
  // Does something with s
  for i:=0;i<len(s.songs);i++ {
    fmt.Printf("s.songs[%d]=\"%s\"\n",i, s.songs[i])
  }
}
```

output:

```
s.songs[0]="Master of Puppets"
s.songs[1]="Battery"
```

In case you really want to test if your structure was properly initialized inside your main function:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myStruct struct {
   songs []string
}

func main() {
  s1 := myStruct{songs:[]string{"Master of Puppets", "Battery"}}
  foo(s1)
  for i:=0;i<len(s1.songs);i++ {
    fmt.Printf("s1.songs[%d]=\"%s\"\n",i, s1.songs[i])
  }
}

func foo(s myStruct) {
  // Does something with s
  fmt.Printf("foo has finished its work!\n")
}
```

output:

```
foo has finished its work!
s1.songs[0]="Master of Puppets"
s1.songs[1]="Battery"
```

If you want to make sure both main() and foo() are working with the same object, try this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myStruct struct {
   songs []string
}

func main() {
  s1 := myStruct{songs:[]string{"Master of Puppets", "Battery"}}
  foo(&s1)
  fmt.Printf("main() says: s1 lives in the address:%p\n",&s1)
}

func foo(s *myStruct) {
  // Does something with s
  fmt.Printf("foo() says: s lives in the address:%p\n",s)
}
```

output:

```
foo() says: s lives in the address:0x10434120
main() says: s1 lives in the address:0x10434120
```

Next time, try being more specific on your questions.

Cheers.